# Am I understanding getopt() correctly?

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to scan the command line for certain letters, symbols and values. I want to scan for `"-w"`, a number, and `"-s"`. I got a response in my last question, I was told to use `getopt()` and after a little bit of Googling, I think I might get it, but I'm not sure.

This is what I think I'm doing:

```
int c = 0; 
int b = argv[2];

while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "-w", "-s", b))
```

I think I'm scanning `argc` for `"-w"`, `"-s"` and the `argv[2]` value (which is the number).  But I do not know if I am using it correctly?

Comment: Check man pages for getopt - how many params does it take - 3. How many are you passing - 4. Does your code even compile?

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop should be
`while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "w:s:"))`

`:` the colon means it needs an argument.  now convert `optarg` to an integer or whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 0;
int sflag = 0;
int opt;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "w:s")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 's':
        sflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'w':
        number = atoi(optarg);
        break;
    default:
        /* Report usage and exit? */
        break;
    }
}
```

The conversion on the number is lazy; you can do more a more careful job calling a function that calls `strtol()`, for instance.  You might need to have a `wflag` variable that you set analogously to the `sflag` variable so that you can distinguish `-w 0` from 'no `-w` option specified on the command line'.

Comment: Now, one thing I'm confused on. When I use getopt or optarg, VS gives me an error, saying both getopt and optarg are undefined. I'm fairly new to C (Only did a few programs thus far) and I'm not sure why I'm getting this problem.

Comment: So you are compiling on Windows with Visual Studio? The last time I checked, the Microsoft runtime library (MSVCRT) did not have a `getopt` function.

Comment: On Unix, [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) is declared in `<unistd.h>`, and that would declare the global variables too. (Historically, some systems declared `getopt()` in `<stdio.h>`, but we can safely assume it isn't there since you got the error.) You'll need to find out whether Microsoft supports it at all, and if so where it declares the function and variables. There's a possibility that it does not do so at all; there's a possibility that it prefixes the names with an underscore. If all else fails, get GNU `getopt()` and its `<getopt.h>`.

Comment: Do a Google (or other search engine of your choice) search on 'getopt source at&t public domain'.  You'll find the source code for a version of `getopt()` that was placed in the public domain by AT&T in about 1985.  You'll need to convert it to ANSI C, but otherwise, you should be good to go.